# Saving, retaining, & retrieving selected cells in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I've read every post and tried every solution multiple times, but cannot get correct functionality.

I have a tableview with data from a local JSON file.  I need the user to be able to:

1. select multiple cells
2. show check marks on selected cells
3. write those selections to an array
4. delete the selections when unchecked

**5. save/retain the selections with the check marks when user switches view or leaves and comes back to tableview, closes and reopens app, etc.**

I've managed to get 1-4 working, but I'm stuck on #5 and can't figure it out for the life of me.  I've tried NSUserDefaults every way I could.  Any help is appreciated.  Below is the current code.

Also, why am I having to double click a cell to uncheck it?

```
@interface FilterViewController () <UISearchResultsUpdating>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *IngredientsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedCell;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedIngredients;
//I added this property to keep track of the selected row
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedPath;


@end

@implementation FilterViewController {
    NSArray *_locations;


}


- (void)viewDidLoad {


    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.selectedIngredients = [NSMutableArray array];
     self.selectedCell = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.lastIndexPath = [defaults objectForKey:@"lastIndexPathUsed"];



    // Create a new JSONLoader with a local file URL
    JSONLoaderIngreds *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoaderIngreds alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"locations" withExtension:@"json"];

    // There's no transition in our storyboard to our search results tableview or navigation controller
    // so we'll have to grab it using the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method
    UINavigationController *searchResultsController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilterViewSearchResultsNavController"];

    // Our instance of UISearchController will use searchResults
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];

    // The searchcontroller's searchResultsUpdater property will contain our tableView.
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;


    // create the searchBar programatically.
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;


    //Sets LocationsViewController as presenter for LocationDetailViewController after searxh results dsiplayed
    //and selected..  Required so searchbar doesn't show in detailsview after segue, and instead, default nav
    //controller back button displays.
    self.definesPresentationContext = true;





    // Load the data on a background queue...
    // As we are using a local file it's not really necessary, but if we were connecting to an online URL then we'd need it
    //NSString *ingreds = [dict objectForKey:@"ingredients"]
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        _locations = [jsonLoader ingredientsFromJSONFile:url];
        // Now that we have the data, reload the table data on the main UI thread
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        });

}

// Just before showing the LocationViewController, set the selected Location object
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    LocationsViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    vc.location = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //I added this if clause to select the row that was last selected
    if (self.selectedPath != nil) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }

}

#pragma mark - Table View Controller Methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     self.selectedPath = indexPath;
    NSString *Ingredient = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath]){
        [self.selectedCell removeObject:indexPath];
        [self.selectedIngredients removeObject:Ingredient];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        [self.selectedCell addObject:indexPath];
        [self.selectedIngredients addObject:Ingredient];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    NSLog(@"***************Selected Ingredients**************** %@", self.selectedIngredients);
    NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userdefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.section] forKey:@"lastIndexPathUsed"];
    [userdefaults synchronize];


}

-(BOOL)isRowSelectedOnTableView:(UITableView *)tableView atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([self.selectedCell containsObject:indexPath]) ? YES : NO;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *unifiedID = @"FilterCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:unifiedID];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:unifiedID];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ingredientsicon3232.png"];

    //if the indexPath was found among the selected ones, set the checkmark on the cell
    cell.accessoryType = ([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;


}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_locations count];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I managed to changed code as suggested to save selections to array in `NSUserDefaults` using the updated code below, but I still can't figure out the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code needed to save/recall checkmarks.

How would I code cellForRowAtIndexPath to recall checkmarks?

Saving selections to array with this code:

ViewDidLoad code:

```
_selections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selections"]];
    if(_selections == nil){
        _selections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    {
    if ([_selections containsObject: cell.textLabel.text] == NO){
        [_selections addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        [_selections removeObject:cell.textLabel.text];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    NSLog(@"***************Selected Ingredients**************** %@", _selections);
    NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [userdefaults setObject:_selections forKey:@"selections"];
    [userdefaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"-------------NSUserDefaults------------%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation])

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is pretty straight forward.

1. First thing is you need to save an array of selected index paths to your user default object instead of just last selected path.
2. Whenever a user selects or deselects a row. Add and remove objects from the same array and save it back to your user defaults.
3. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, check whether your index path exists in the array saved in the user defaults. If it exists, select the row with checkmark otherwise leave it as it is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I understand, but could you show how that would be done in code?  I've tried several different ways and couldn't get to work.  Still learning. Thanks.

Comment: I am travelling right now. May be in a few hours i can show you an example, but right now you should try these three steps and you'll get it. It's not at all difficult. Just give it a go.

Comment: Following your instruction, I've managed to do save selections to array stored in user defaults, but I cannot figure out the code to retain the checkmarks.  Are you able to provide code example?

Comment: Can you share the code where you have saved the array in the user defaults.

Comment: See updates posted in question.  Any helps appreciated.

Comment: I added the code as requested.  Are you able to provide corrections?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of working with those `indexPath`, i recommended you to work straight with the data itself, add a `Bool` property to indicate the selection in your `Ingredient` class, then save the whole array in `CoreData/Realm/NSUserDefault`, that way is more correctly since your data can be change, lead to the selection `indexPath` that you save can be not correct anymore